# Etymology of "kimpeturin"

Tags: yiddish, etymology, women, pregnancy-birth

What is the etymology of the yiddish term "kimpeturin," which refers to a woman who is recovering after childbirth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [yaavetz](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/347/yaavetz) and Google, I have [discovered](http://bhol-forums.co.il/topic.asp?topic_id=2375464&forum_id=19616) that the source is the German and/or Yiddish "Kindbett" -- the bed upon which a woman who has just given birth convalesces.

Answer (score 2):

interesting. no firm source, but if i would have to guess, it would SEEM to be:
kim + peturin

where kim = get up
peturin = as in peter rechem, the opening up of the womb

Comment: So you're saying the source is Aramaic? (Maybe you've read "Words on Fire"... http://muse.jhu.edu/journals/journal_of_american_folklore/v122/122.483.gilman.html) It's definitely a creative suggestion, but not very likely to be accurate. For one thing, "peter rechem" refers specifically to the first issue of the womb. "Yoledes" (or its Aramaic counterpart) would have been a much more appropriate term.

Comment: "kimpet" means childbirth. So your guess is unlikely.

Comment: @yaavetz - in which language? It does not sound like a 'native' yiddish word.

Comment: indeed, the etymology I offered is spurious. here is the wiktionary entry for kimpeturin, http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%A4%D6%BC%D7%A2%D7%98%D7%90%D6%B8%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9F, which comes from kimpet.